# Explicitly setting colorbar bins in plt.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I have created a scatter plot over a basemap of the U.S. using `pyplot.scatter` in which the bins of the color bar are evenly spaced over the range of the input data.  However, I would like to explicitly control the bins of the color bar in order to create uneven bins, e.g. `[-20, -10, -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,50]` instead of evenly spaced bins between `-20` and `50`. How can this be done?

Comment: You mean create uneven bins of discrete colorbars? Or just setting your own ticks to those values in the list?

Comment: Setting my own ticks to values in that list to have non-regular ticks. like in this plot: https://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/ngeo/journal/v9/n7/carousel/ngeo2721-f4.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your own ticks in a colorbar in `plt.scatter` you can change `ticks` parameter in [`fig.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) to whatever list of values you desire:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
xy = range(20)
z = xy
sc = plt.scatter(xy, xy, c=z, vmin=0, vmax=20, s=35, cmap=cm)

cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, ticks=[0, 1, 15])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, but I guess my original answer to your question was wrong. I would like to create bins that represent differently sized ranges of numbers, but are evenly spaced on the colorbar. like this: https://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/ngeo/journal/v9/n7/carousel/ngeo2721-f4.jpg

Comment: @jimutters Oh, ok, but I think my solution can work that out, can't it? I mean, you just would have to set the values in a discrete colorbar, or are those numbers in the colobar "fictional" and do not represent the real values being assigned?

Comment: To get a discrete colormap, just replace the 3rd line of code to `cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu',10)` for example, tick's assignment still works.